# python minidom parse XML feed with colon in results

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse an XML feed that displays NFL schedules, one of the attributes is the game time and it looks like this GameTime="8:30 PM"

Here's a clip of what the XML looks like

```
<Schedule Season="2010" Timezone="Eastern">
  <Game gameId="1" Week="1" GameDate="2010-09-09" AwayTeam="MIN" HomeTeam="NO" GameTime="8:30 PM"/>
  <Game gameId="2" Week="1" GameDate="2010-09-12" AwayTeam="MIA" HomeTeam="BUF" GameTime="1:00 PM"/>
  <Game gameId="3" Week="1" GameDate="2010-09-12" AwayTeam="DET" HomeTeam="CHI" GameTime="1:00 PM"/>
  <Game gameId="4" Week="1" GameDate="2010-09-12" AwayTeam="OAK" HomeTeam="TEN" GameTime="1:00 PM"/>
</Schedule>
```

Here's my code to read it

```
url="http://example.com/schedule.xml"
dom = minidom.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))

for node in dom.getElementsByTagName('Game'):
    print node.getAttribute('AwayTeam'),
    print node.getAttribute('HomeTeam'),
    print node.getAttribute('Week'),
    print node.getAttribute('gameId'),
    print node.getAttribute('GameDate'),
    print node.getAttribute('GameTime')
```

It prints what I'd expect until I add that last line.  ETA: Once this last line is added, it goes from printing lines from the XML to nothing.

```
 print node.getAttribute('GameTime')
```

I'd assume it is because there is a colon in the returned data, but I can't find anything to assist me with either escaping that to allow it to print or ignoring it.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: @Mike: Please edit your question to include what is the actual behaviour: mangled output? if so, show the output. error message? if so, show the error message and the full traceback. Is there any reason that you can't show the actual URL?

Comment: @John - Thanks for the reply, I edited the question to include how it's broken.  I wasn't showing the actual URL because it includes an API key in it, but it appears that the API key can be anything so here it is.  http://api.fantasyfootballnerd.com/ffnScheduleXML.php?apiKey=1

Comment: @Mike: I just used the URL you provided and again I didn't have a problem.

Comment: @dappawit - Great, thank you for testing. I will do some of the testing I mentioned below and see if it's something specific to GAE.  I appreciate the help.  Thank you.

Comment: I have officially lost my mind.  I used your example dappawit and it worked, I then stepped the code back to exactly like my example, still works. I found a syntax error earlier in the code. Thank you both for your help, I have it working now.

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your error, but it printed just fine for me.

I tried loading your data from a string within the Python module, I tried loading your data from a named file, and I tried loading your data from a file object.  They all handled the colon just fine.

The only difference now seems to be the way you get the data: urllib2.openurl().  Perhaps the data returned by that function is not exactly what minidom expects.  Or perhaps it does something with the colon character.

Here is the code I used (The test.xml file contains the same xml data as in the triple-quoted string):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

src = """
<Schedule Season="2010" Timezone="Eastern">
  <Game gameId="1" Week="1" GameDate="2010-09-09" AwayTeam="MIN" HomeTeam="NO" GameTime="8:30 PM"/>
  <Game gameId="2" Week="1" GameDate="2010-09-12" AwayTeam="MIA" HomeTeam="BUF" GameTime="1:00 PM"/>
  <Game gameId="3" Week="1" GameDate="2010-09-12" AwayTeam="DET" HomeTeam="CHI" GameTime="1:00 PM"/>
  <Game gameId="4" Week="1" GameDate="2010-09-12" AwayTeam="OAK" HomeTeam="TEN" GameTime="1:00 PM"/>
</Schedule>
"""

def test_print(dom):
    for node in dom.getElementsByTagName('Game'):
        print node.getAttribute('AwayTeam'),
        print node.getAttribute('HomeTeam'),
        print node.getAttribute('Week'),
        print node.getAttribute('gameId'),
        print node.getAttribute('GameDate'),
        print node.getAttribute('GameTime')
    print ''

dom = minidom.parseString(src)
test_print(dom)

dom = minidom.parse('data.xml')
test_print(dom)

f = open('data.xml', 'r')
dom = minidom.parse(f)
test_print(dom)
f.close()

url = 'http://api.fantasyfootballnerd.com/ffnScheduleXML.php?apiKey=1'
dom = minidom.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))
test_print(dom)
```

Edits: Added test for URL provided by Mike (original post author).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the above question to include the original XML URL.  I will test with a local file and the src like you did to see if it makes a difference.  This is using Google App Engine if that makes any difference, but I figured since I had it reading everything except the GameTime, it was just a syntax error.